# laravel foreach json response not working right

Tags: json, laravel

I'm having a problem with a soap response in laravel...

I'm calling the soap in the controller like this :

```
   public function users()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();  
        
        $users = User::all();
        
       // webservice X3                
        $soapclient = new SoapClient($this->WSDL, $this->params);
         
        // method x3
        $wsname = 'ZWSUSR01';
        
        $xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
        $xml.='<PARAM>';
        $xml.='</PARAM>';
 
        $result = $soapclient->run($this->CContext, $wsname, $xml);
        
        $status = $result->status;  
        $i=0;
        if ($status == 1) { 
            
             $xml = simplexml_load_string($result->resultXml);
                    foreach ($xml->TAB->LIN as $line) {
                        $x3users[$i]= array();                        
                        foreach ($line->FLD as $name) {
                            $x3users[$i]["".$name['NAME'].""] = (string)$name;
                        }
                        $i++;
                    }

                    $x3users= json_encode($x3users, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );

        } else {
            $message = $result->resultXml;         
                $vars = array(
                    'xwebservice' => $wsname,
                    'xident' => $id,
                    'xmessage' => $message
                );       
            $this->erroRotinas($vars); 
            $xml='';

        }
        
        return view('configs.users', compact(['users', 'x3users']));
    }
```

When i call in the view the response using `{{ $x3users }}` it gives me the result in json and it looks fine `[{...},{...},{...}]`

But if I do `@foreach($x3users as $x3user)` it returns `Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View:`

What can it be?

Comment: you are json encoding the variable so it is a string. Remove line `$x3users= json_encode($x3users, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );` if you intend to iterate through that variable

Comment: @apokryfos if i do that i get ```htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View:```

Comment: I am assuming you are doing both the `{{ ... }}` and `foreach` on the same thing. The first requires a string and the 2nd requires an array. You can probably do `{{ json_encode($x3users, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); }}` in the view so you retain the array and convert it to a string only when you need it

Comment: @apokryfos you're right i was using ```{{ $x3user }}``` inside the foreach, my mistake :D...
Thanks... that solves my problem